# Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to create the following shiny app below but when Im tryin to subset based on my widget I get: `Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

```
## app.R ##

#Libraries needed fot the app
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(hrbrthemes)
Targets2<-structure(list(Week = c(1, 1, 7, 7, 16, 16, 14, 14, 20, 20, 15, 
                                  15, 7, 7, 2, 2, 10, 10, 15, 15), Type = c("Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target"), Count = c(5, 
                                                                                                                                              7, 123, 18, 348, 33, 298, 37, 448, 52, 323, 29, 123, 18, 13, 
                                                                                                                                              12, 198, 8, 323, 29)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"))
#The ui part contains the user interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
  #Contains the title
  dashboardHeader(title = "Clinics Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    #Contains the sidebar with the date range input
    
    selectInput("weeks", "Select Week(s):",
                choices=unique(Targets2$Week ),selected=unique(Targets2$Week ),
                multiple=T)
    
    
  ),
  #the body contains the 2 plots
  dashboardBody(
    #1st plot
    plotlyOutput("plot")
    
  )
)
#the server part contains all the background code that is displayed in the ui part
server <- function(input, output) {
  Targets2<-reactive({
    Targets2 <- subset(Targets2, Targets2$Week %in% input$weeks)
  })
  #the code for creating the 1st plot
  output$plot<-renderPlotly({
    
    p <-
      ggplot(Targets2(), aes(x = Week, y = Count, fill = Type))+
      geom_area(alpha = 0.6 , size = 0.5, colour = "white", stat = "identity", orientation = "x") +
      theme_ipsum() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom")
    p <- p+labs(title = "Figure 1: Weekly Cumulative Projected Enrollment vs Weekly Cumulative Actual Enrollment",
                subtitle = "Cum Weekly Projected Enrollment/Cum Weekly Actual Enrollment")
    
    
    ggplotly(p)
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: An obscure hint to this is knowing that in R, a "closure" is effectively a function in its defining environment. Knowing that, if the error (don't see it here) includes the `Targets2` *name*, then look for all definitions that might be construed as functions. A common reason for this type of error is defining data in a object named one of `data` or `df`, then restarting R for some reason, and not redefining it ... and trying to do data-like operations on the base functions with the same names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of the `reactive` function or change the name of the dataset. They both share the same name hence, the error.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(hrbrthemes)

Targets<-structure(list(Week = c(1, 1, 7, 7, 16, 16, 14, 14, 20, 20, 15, 
                                  15, 7, 7, 2, 2, 10, 10, 15, 15), Type = c("Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
                                                                            "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target"), Count = c(5, 
                                                                                                                                              7, 123, 18, 348, 33, 298, 37, 448, 52, 323, 29, 123, 18, 13, 
                                                                                                                                              12, 198, 8, 323, 29)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"))
#The ui part contains the user interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
  #Contains the title
  dashboardHeader(title = "Clinics Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    #Contains the sidebar with the date range input
    
    selectInput("weeks", "Select Week(s):",
                choices=unique(Targets2$Week ),selected=unique(Targets2$Week ),
                multiple=T)
    
    
  ),
  #the body contains the 2 plots
  dashboardBody(
    #1st plot
    plotlyOutput("plot")
    
  )
)
#the server part contains all the background code that is displayed in the ui part
server <- function(input, output) {
  Targets2<-reactive({
    Targets2 <- subset(Targets, Targets$Week %in% input$weeks)
  })
  #the code for creating the 1st plot
  output$plot<-renderPlotly({
    
    p <-
      ggplot(Targets2(), aes(x = Week, y = Count, fill = Type))+
      geom_area(alpha = 0.6 , size = 0.5, colour = "white", stat = "identity", orientation = "x") +
      theme_ipsum() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom")
    p <- p+labs(title = "Figure 1: Weekly Cumulative Projected Enrollment vs Weekly Cumulative Actual Enrollment",
                subtitle = "Cum Weekly Projected Enrollment/Cum Weekly Actual Enrollment")
    
    
    ggplotly(p)
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: oh so simple it was